# HikariCP (пул соединений) перестает выдавать соединения

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, hikaricp

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой в которой не могу разобраться.
Подключил HikariCP, пользователей приложения около 50 человек, ~ через час пул соединений перестает выдавать соединения (HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 3000ms.)
Задавал разные настройки и тайминги, но проблема не исчезает, единственное что я придумал это создавать принудительно нативное соединение(но оно долго создается и интерфейс приложения подтормаживает).
БД - PostgreSQL

Вот мой код:

```
   public enum MyConnectionPool {
            INSTANCE();
            private HikariDataSource dataSource;
            MyConnectionPool() {
            if(dataSource==null) {
                HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
                config.setDriverClassName(ConnectionProperty.DRIVER_NAME.getValue());
                config.setJdbcUrl(ConnectionProperty.URL.getValue());
        
                config.setUsername(ConnectionProperty.LOGIN.getValue());
                config.setPassword(ConnectionProperty.PASS.getValue());
                config.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts","true");
                config.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize","250");
                config.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit","2048");
                /*Перепробовал кучу параметров */
                config.setMaximumPoolSize(80);
                config.setMinimumIdle(30);
                config.setIdleTimeout(0);
                config.setConnectionTimeout(3000);//3 секунды
                config.setMaxLifetime(0);
                config.setKeepaliveTime(60000);//10мин
                config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(2000);
        
                dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
                }
        
        
        
            }
            public   Connection getConn(){
                if(dataSource!=null) {
                    try {
                        return dataSource.getConnection();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        try {
        
                            Notification.show("Не получил соединение из пула, создал новое:"+e.getMessage());
                        }catch (Exception e1){
        
                        }
                        //~ через час начинает срабатывать принудительное создание подключения и начинаются тормоза
                        return CRMDatabaseConnection.getDatabaseConnection();
        
                    }
                }else {
                    try {
                        Notification.show("dataSource IS NULL, создал новое соединение");
                    }catch (Exception e1){
        
                    }
                    return CRMDatabaseConnection.getDatabaseConnection();
                    //return null;
                }
        
            }
        
        
            public HikariDataSource getDataSource() {
                return dataSource;
            }
        
     }
```

Обращаюсь к базе вот таким способом:

```
try(Connection connection = MyConnectionPool.INSTANCE.getConn()){
  String sql = "SELECT .................."
   Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                ..................... 
            }
            rs.close;
            stmt.close; 

}catch (Exception e){

}
```

Такое ощущение что пул создает соединения,
после того как я использую соединение я его закрываю, соединение в пуле становится  закрытым, и при повторном обращении к пулу он мне и выдает закрытое соединение. Хотя по логике connection (это HikariProxyConnection), и закрывая его я по cути говорю пулу, что соединение может использовать кто то другой, т.е физически оно не должно закрываться

Делаю тесты:

```
  int counter = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            try (Connection connection  = MyConnectionPool.INSTANCE.getConn()) {
                System.out.println(connection);
                String sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) AS COUNT from sys_leads LIMIT 100";
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()){
                    int count = rs.getInt("COUNT");
                    System.out.println(count);
                    counter++;
                }
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println("ошибка:"+e);
            }

            System.out.println("итерация:"+counter);
        }
```

Пул возвращает одно и тоже соединение и как бы все нормально, ошибок нет.
Если реализовать этот код в разных потоках то тоже все нормально, на каждый поток возвращается свое соединение и проблем нет

Comment: Что показывает лог? Включить нужно для логера `com.zaxxer.hikari` с уровнем `DEBUG` или даже `TRACE`. Там самое интересное в данном случае, это состояние пула, количество активных соединение, общее количество, количество свободных и т.д. Нужно увидеть это состояние в момент, когда случается проблема.

Comment: Доступ к логам рабочего сервера, затруднен (нужно тысячу писем написать), время займет. Но косвенно если смотреть не на пул, а в мониторинг подключений к бд (idle connections ~30, активных соединений в единицу времени 1-5)